# Track the Path between two points on google map without using navigation SDK

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-maps, polyline

I am creating an app in which I want to track the path of a Driver from his source to his destination how I can achieve the goal without using Navigation SDK? How i can update the Lattitude and Longitude? Right now I am using polyline to draw the path between source and Destination. and I am using only Google Map

I want to show the live path tracking of the driver on Google Map when he is going to his Destination.

Answer (score 1):

You should to call the api every 3-5 seconds and then you will get the new lat and long you can update the map in a api calling function into the `dispatch.quee.main`

Comment: Does it increase the loading time? or sometime if the server fails to give response on time ?

Comment: (1) No it does not increase the loading time ask to bakend devloper then after how much time they fetch the lat, log of the vehicle from the databases whatever time they took you can call the same api again after the same time so you can get the new values of lat and log (2) if you did not recive the responce from the server that time you can use the previous lat, log values that would be helpfull